# Does Spring Boot 2 support Java 10?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Since Spring has confirmed Spring Boot 2 will support Java9 and Java 8 being minimum version to run Spring Boot 2 application. Now that Java is planning to release Java 11, does Spring Boot 2 will support Java 10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Java 10 is supported as of Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE. We intend to support Java 11 as of Spring Boot 2.1.x

See: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-with-Java-9-and-above

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I use it on production with Java 10 and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Java 10 is supported as of Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE. Java 11 is supported as of Spring Boot 2.1.0.M2. The plan is to officially support Java 12 as of Spring Boot 2.2